# View my database in sqlite3

Tags: android, sqlite, terminal

I want to look into the contents of my database on my Android device. I have tried again and again through Terminal Emulator on the Android Emulator to open up my database, but I can't figure out what I am missing.

My database's file name is "tasks_db.sqlite"

At the prompt I type

```
 sqlite3 tasks_db.sqlite
 SELECT * FROM tasks
```

This results in

> SQL ERROR: Not An Error

What am I doing wrong? Is it because I am not in the correct directory?

My pwd (print working directory) all the time was `\`

Comment: As a first check, get the list of tables in your database by entering ".tables" at the prompt. Do you see the "tasks" table in that listing?

Comment: it not reply with anything on the prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Run `adb shell`
2. Move to the data directory of yours application which is usually in
   the following path: `/data/data/<package_name>` using command `cd
   /data/data/<package_name>`
3. Find database file in subfolders. Usually database file is under
   `database` subdirectory.
4. Run `sqlite3 tasks_db.sqlite`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the full path to the database file. Unless you are in your databases directory, `sqlite3 tasks_db.sqlite` will work with an empty database file.

You might consider using MOTODEV Studio for Android (offers SQLite editing from within Eclipse), or downloading the database using DDMS and using some other SQLite utility (e.g., SQLite Manager extension for Firefox).

Comment: what is the name of the database directory?

Comment: @Prometheus87: Usually something like `/data/data/your.package.name.goes.here/databases`

Comment: Do you have root on the device? Assuming so, since you said Terminal Emulator but maybe you've somehow lost root. The data will be in /data/data and then the path to your package. As Mark mentioned, MOTODEV Studio allows you access to this with the Android Emulator or devices with root access (dev phones, etc.).